# PostgresSQL creating column that automatically fill another column?

Tags: mysql, postgresql, dbeaver

I'm pretty new in postgres so I don't know if this possible.

I want to create a column in my table that can automatically fill the next column.
For example:

```
CREATE TABLE table_name (
    id bigserial NOT NULL,
    inspectionDate date NOT NULL,
    next_inspection_date date NOT NULL
);
```

So if 'inspectionDate' column is filled today, say 2020-06-28, can the 'next_inspection_date' column automatically fill with a date 3 years later (2023-06-28)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a generated column:

```
CREATE TABLE table_name (
    id bigserial NOT NULL,
    inspectionDate date NOT NULL,
    next_inspection_date date NOT NULL
        GENERATED ALWAYS AS (inspectionDate + INTERVAL '3 year') STORED
);
```

The generated column should automatically be populated with a date 3 years from the `inspectionDate` column, anytime there is an insert or update.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using PostgreSQL 12 then you can use generated column

https://pgdash.io/blog/postgres-12-generated-columns.html

https://severalnines.com/database-blog/overview-generated-columns-postgresql